# I want the data from the input to be output to the console when clicked, but for some reason they are output with every change in the ipnut

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function Text() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="white">
```

> input from which I need to catch information

```
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter" onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={console.log(text)}>CLICK</button>

      <div>{text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `<button onClick={() => {console.log(text)}}>CLICK</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use arrow function in button:

```js
<button onClick={() => console.log(text)}>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you put the function like this in `onClick` :

```js
<button onClick={console.log(text)}>CLICK</button>
```

This will make it execute each time the component rerender, however :

```js
<button onClick={() => {console.log(text)}}>CLICK</button>
```

will make it execute each time the button is clicked